# How can I move files(based on time) to some other location in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: batch, script, windows-server-2008-r2

Can one any help me with the script in moving the files to another location if my disk space is used more than 90%.

For example:

I have a database running in my E:/ drive and it is around 350 GB Total. My database is 320 GB. some files will be generated in hourly basis to E: location.
In case if my E: drive is full, that will result in some serious issues like database down.

Hence if the E:/ drive is more than 90%, I have to move some bunch of files in the same location E:\PROD\Archive_log\ into another location C:\Backup_ARC_log\

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes David, I will explain what i have tried so far.